# Text Blurs with Animation Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So the text is blurring when animating its scale to 1.1 using an animation in kivy. I'm sure it's because the font size is static this entire time and is being stretched as a result.

Is there a way to increase scale size of text using an animation while keeping its clarity?

I've also noticed a strange issue where when they enlarge, all the other widgets above are pushed as well. I'm trying to localize it. This is my .kv file.

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory
#:import HoverButton BasicUI.HoverButton
#:import changeTypeToId Database.changeTypeToId
#:import utils kivy.utils


<ChangeButton@HoverButton>:
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    markup: True
    font_size: 32
    size_hint: None, None
    width:  self.texture_size[0] + 5
    height: self.texture_size[1] + 5 if self.texture_size[1] != 0 else 46
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix:
        Scale:
            origin: self.x + 0.5*self.width, self.y + 0.5*self.height
            x: self.scale
            y: self.scale

    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix:

<SmallChangeButton@HoverButton>:
    markup: True
    font_size: 16
    size_hint: None, None
    width:  self.texture_size[0] + 5
    height: self.texture_size[1] + 5 if self.texture_size[1] != 0 else 24
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    on_enter: self.setFontSize(20)
    on_leave: self.setFontSize(16)

<ChooseChangeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            x: 20
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: None, None
            width:  self.texture_size[0] + 5
            font_name: "TitleFont"
            text: "JARVIS"
        Label:
            font_size: 16
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": .98}
            size_hint: None, None
            width:  self.texture_size[0] + 5
            height: self.texture_size[1] + 50
            color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#05eeff')
            markup: True
            text: "[b]Xari[/b]"
        BoxLayout:
            x: 20
            pos_hint: { "top": .5}
            size_hint_x: .5
            size_hint_y: None
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 3
            ChangeButton:
                text: "[i][b]ADD CHANGES[/i][/b]"
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = .5
                    root.manager.current = 'MainMenu'
            ChangeButton:
                text: "[b][i]MODIFY CHANGES[/i][/b]"
            SmallChangeButton:
            SmallChangeButton:
                """)
```

The animations are

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    self.initial_font = self.font_size
    anim = Animation(font_size=self.font_size * 1.2, duration=.07)
    anim.start(self)

def on_leave(self, *args):
    anim = Animation(font_size=self.initial_font, duration=.07)
    anim.start(self)
```